# cannot find default constructor to initialize member in cpp

Tags: c++, constructor

Please help me with this. I was trying to fix this for two hours.
This is my code.

```
class deviceC {

private:
    deviceA devA;
    deviceB devB;
    wayPoint destination,current;

public: 
    deviceC(wayPoint destination1){
        destination=destination1;
        devA=deviceA();
        devB=deviceB();
    }
};
```

This is the error:

> cannot find default constructor to initialize member
>   'deviceC::destination' in function deviseC::destination(wayPoint)

Comment: Please post more code. Where are you trying to create an object of type `deviceC`?

Comment: Can we see the constructors of wayPoint?

Comment: thaks everyone. it is working after add an initializer list like  @songyuanyao said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an initializer list in your constructor, because member `destination` and `current` with type `wayPoint` does not has a default constructor.

```
class deviceC {
public: 
    deviceC(wayPoint destination1) : destination(destination1) {
        devA=deviceA();
        devB=deviceB();
    }
};
```

And IMO, you don't need init the `devA` and `devB` inside the constructor just with the default constructor, they just call the `operator=` after their default constructor called. Here's my suggestion:

```
class deviceC {
private:
    deviceA devA;
    deviceB devB;
    wayPoint destination, current;
public: 
    deviceC(const wayPoint& destination1, const wayPoint& current1) : destination(destination1), current(current1) {}
};
```

Comment: it is working now. I had to initialize the other variable "current" too. thanks..

Comment: @kasunbdn I've edited my answer to give some more suggestion, hope it helps.

Comment: yeah it was very helpful. i was coding in java and now trying to do with c++.  but couldn't get     "you don't need init the devA and devB inside the constructor just with the default constructor"      so when we initialize devA and B?

Comment: @kasunbdn They will be initialized by default constructor when you write `private: deviceA devA; deviceA devB;`. You don't need do anything else such as `deviceA devA = new deviceA();` like Java. If you want them initialized by their other constructor with some parameters, you can use the initializer list to change the behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Missed a bracket.

```
class deviceC{

    private : deviceA devA;
                  deviceB devB;
                  wayPoint destination,current;

    public: deviceC(wayPoint destination1){
            destination=destination1;
            devA=deviceA();
            devB=deviceB();
    } // <-- here
};
```

Comment: sorry. i was a mistake when i copied the code here. thakns. it is working now