# Recursive constructors in C++

Tags: c++, constructor, default-constructor

I build a class for containing vectors with no default constructor. Specifically:

```
template<typename T>
struct MyVector
{
public:
  int GetN(void)
  {
    return n;
  }
  MyVector(int n1)
  {
    n=n1;
    ListElt = new T[n1];
  }
  ~MyVector()
  {
    delete [] ListElt;
  }
  // some other irrelevant to the question code
private:
  int n;
  T *ListElt;
};
```

Now I want to build a class derived from it that contains one integer and a vector.
The code that works is the following:

```
struct EquivInfo {
public:
  EquivInfo(int inpOrbit, MyVector<int> &inpMat)
  {
    iOrbit=inpOrbit;
    eVect=new MyVector<int>(inpMat.getN());
    // some code for copying the vector in place.
  }
  ~EquivInfo()
  {
    delete eVect;
  }
private:
  int iOrbit;
  MyVector<int> *eVect;
};
```

Is there a way to avoid the use of the pointer for the vector?

The problem is that if I remove the pointer then there is a call to a constructor of the kind **MyVector()**. I do not understand why. There should be a way to have a constructor for EquivInfo that calls a precise constructor for **MyVector**

I could add a constructor **MyVector()**, i.e. a default constructor that set the vector to something trivial. But precisely, I want to avoid such kind of constructors so that all vectors are well defined and the code is clean. The use of the pointer allows me to have a reasonable situation but I wonder if there is a clean way to avoid it.

Comment: use `std::vector<>` or `std::array<>` (your implementation is already bugged) ? Else, what don't you use the initialization list in your second class ?

Comment: Where is the "recursion" here?

Comment: Also, it sounds like you need to read up on [initialization lists](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=c%2B%2B+initialization+list).

Comment: Duplicate of for example [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22852436/cannot-find-default-constructor-to-initialize-member-in-cpp). The answer is to use an initializer list.

Comment: What if you do MyVector<int> eVect(inpMat.getN()); ?

Comment: Next time post the code that is not working (as opposed to posting the code that is working and then describing what wasn't working)

Comment: Note that not defining a default constructor does not mean it is not available. The compiler generally offers it automatically (hence it's called 'default'). To succinctly remove such, either define it as private (old method) or use the delete keyword (since C++11).

Answer (score 5):

Use [member initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list):

```
class EquivInfo {
 public:
  EquivInfo(int inpOrbit, MyVector<int> &inpMat) 
    : eVect(inpMat.getN())
    , iOrbit(inpOrbit) {
    // some code for copying the vector in place.
   }

   // ....

   MyVector<int> eVect;
}
```

Comment: He! You could also add `iOrbit(inpOrbit)` to that list... 8-)

Comment: Thank you. That was the part that I was missing.

Comment: @MathieuDutourSikiric: I'm glad it helped you and I'm looking forward to seeing an accept of this answer from you.